# Why is my query wrong?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

before i use alias for table i get the error:

: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Then i used aliases and i get this error:

unknown index a

I am trying to get a list of category name ( dependant to a translation) and the associated category id which is unique. Since i need to put them in a select, i see that i should use the lists.

```
 $categorie= DB::table('cat as a')              
                    ->join('campo_cat as c','c.id_cat','=','a.id')
                    ->join('campo as d','d.id','=','c.id_campo')
                    ->join('cat_nome as nome','nome.id_cat','=','a.id')
                    ->join('lingua','nome.id_lingua','=','lingua.id')
                    ->where('lingua.lingua','=','it-IT')
                    ->groupby('nome.nome')
                    ->lists('nome.nome','a.id');
```

Comment: what do you want? this your query?

Comment: probably it has nothing do with the query but somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jmail said, you didn't really describe the problem very well, just what you ended up doing to get around (part of) it. However, if I read your question right you're saying that originally you did it without all the aliases you got the 'ambiguous' error.

So let me explain that first: this would happen, because there are many parts of that query that use `id` rather than a qualified `` table`.`id ``.

if you think about it, without aliases you query looks a bit like this: `` SELECT * FROM `cat` JOIN `campo_cat` ON `id_cat` = `id` JOIN `campo` ON `id` = `id_campo`; `` and suddenly, MySQL doesn't know to which table all these `id` columns refer. So to get around that all you need to do is namespace your fields (i.e. use `` ... JOIN `campo` ON `campo`.`id` = `campo_cat`.`id_campo`... ``). In your case you've gone one step further and aliased your tables. This certianly makes the query a little simpler, though you don't need to actually do it.

So on to your next issue - this will be a Laravel error. And presumably happening because your `key` column from `lists($valueColumn, $keyColumn)` isn't found in the results. This is because you're referring to the `cat.id` column (okay in your aliased case `a.id`) in part of the code that's no longer in MySQL - the `lists()` method is actually run in PHP after Laravel gets the results from the database. As such, there's no such column called `a.id`. It's likely it'll be called `id`, but because you don't request it specifically, you may find that the ambiguous issue is back. My suggestion would be to select it specifically and alias the column. Try something like the below:

```
$categories = DB::table('cat as a')              
                  ->join('campo_cat as c','c.id_cat','=','a.id')
                  ->join('campo as d','d.id','=','c.id_campo')
                  ->join('cat_nome as nome','nome.id_cat','=','a.id')
                  ->join('lingua','nome.id_lingua','=','lingua.id')
                  ->where('lingua.lingua','=','it-IT')
                  ->groupby('nome.nome')
                  ->select('nome.nome as nome_nome','a.id as a_id') // here we alias `.id as a_id
                  ->lists('nome_nome','a_id'); // here we refer to the actual columns
```

It may not work perfectly (I don't use `->select()` so don't know whether you pass an array or multiple parameters, also you may need `DB::raw()` wrapping each one in order to do the aliasing) but hopefully you get my meaning and can get it working.

Comment: I find out that you are right, I found out that I can use aliases in select but I can't use aliases in lists.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to debug your query is to look at the raw query Laravel generates and trying to run this raw query in your favorite SQL tool (Navicat, MySQL cli tool...), so you can dump it to log using:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) { 
    Log::info($sql); 
    Log::info($bindings); 
});
```

Doing that with yours I could see at least one problem:

```
->where('lingua.lingua','=','it-IT')
```

Must be changed to

```
->where('lingua.lingua','=',"'it-IT'")
```